# Difference in code execution when extension method present but not called

Tags: c#, extension-methods, mstest, jit

**TL;DR, The question:**

What effect on the execution of code can the presence of an extension method have in .NET (e.g. JIT/optimizations)?

**Background**

I'm experiencing a test failure in MSTest that depends on whether a seemingly unrelated assembly is also tested.

I noticed the test failure and by accident noticed that the failure only occured if another test assembly was loaded. Running mstest on both the Unittests and Integration test assemblies would start executing the integration tests and fail on the 21st integration test under the 4.5 CLR, whereas this does not happen under the 4.0 CLR (same configuration otherwise). 
I removed all the tests but the failing one from the integration test assembly. Execution now looks like this with both test assemblies loaded, mstest loads both assemblies then executes the single test in the integration test assembly, which fails.

```
> mstest.exe /testcontainer:Unittests.dll /testcontainer:IntegrationTests.dll

Loading C:\Proj\Tests\bin\x86\Release\Unittests.dll...
Loading C:\Proj\Tests\bin\x86\Release\Integrationtests.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Failed                Proj.IntegrationTest.IntegrationTest21
```

Without the Unittests assembly in the execution, the test passes.

```
> mstest.exe /testcontainer:IntegrationTests.dll

Loading C:\Proj\Tests\bin\x86\Release\Integrationtests.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Passed                Proj.IntegrationTest.IntegrationTest21
```

I thought it must be an `[AssemblyInitialize]` thing being executed on the UnitTests dll, or perhaps a some sort of static state in the Unittest.dll or a common dependency being modified when the test assembly was loaded. I find neither any static constructors nor assembly init in the Unittests.dll. I suspected a deployment difference when the Unittests assembly was included, (dependent assembly deployed in different version etc.) but I compared the passing/failing deployment dirs and they are binary equivalent.

So what part of the Unittests assembly is causing the test difference?
From the unit tests I removed half the tests at a time until I drilled it down to a source file in the Unit tests assembly. Along with the test class, an extension method is declared:

Apart from this extension class the Unittest assembly now contains a single test case in a dummy test class. The test failure occurs only if I have a dummy test method *and* the extension method declared. I could remove all of the remaining test logic until the Unittest dll is a single file, containing this:

```
// DummyTest.cs in Unittests.dll
[TestClass]
public class DummyTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestNothing()
    {
    }
}

public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> SymmetricDifference<T>(
       this IEnumerable<T> @this,         
       IEnumerable<T> that) 
   {
      return @this.Except(that).Concat(that.Except(@this));
   }
}
```

If either the test method *or* the extension class is removed, the test passes. Both present, and the test fails.

There are no calls to the extension method made from either assembly, and no code is executed in the Unittests assembly before the integration tests are executed (as far as I'm aware).

I'm sure the integration test is complex enough that JIT differences in optimization can cause a difference e.g. in floating point. Is that what I'm seeing?

Comment: I wouldn't say the Extensions class is causing any issues. It's ultimately syntactic sugar, that is replaced at compile time: `var1.SymmetricDifference(var2)` is replaced with  `IEnumerableExtension.SymmetricDifference(var1, var2)`.

Comment: What is the exact error message or exception?  Is there anything in the Event Log?  If you are doing an Assert in your test, what is the actual code of the test that reports Failure.

Comment: There is nothing in the event log, and the only exception is the AssertFailed, which comes from a comparison of floating point results in the test. I can't produce a minimal repro of the problem.

Comment: What happens if you compile and run these tests in Debug mode? What are the compared values that cause Assert to fail? Have you tried replacing `SymmetricDifference` with a simple `return that` or `throw new NotImplementedException`?

Comment: The problem only shows up in an optimized build, and the contents of the extension method does not appear to matter as long as its assembly is loaded. It is never called by the test.

Comment: @Anders Forsgren: 'As long as the assembly is loaded', isn't loading the assembly what actually makes the difference?

Comment: Yes, if it is loaded and contains the extension method, the behaviour changes. I suspect removing the test method would prevent it from loading, whereas removing the extension method prevents the difference in optimization somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue occurs due to type loading error.

When CLR runtime loads a class or method it always inspects all the types used in those items.  It does not matter if type/method is actually called or not. What matters is the fact of declaration. Returning to your sample, the extension method `SymmetricDifference` declares that it uses `Except` and `Concat` methods from System.Core assembly.

What happens there is the error during loading of type `System.Linq.Enumerable` from System.Core assembly.

The reasons for that behavior can vary. The very first step to take is to log the exact exception you get on a test failure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I havent't seen any exceptions though (no TypeLoaderExceptions etc.). I can use the extension method if I want and it works as expected. The test failure looks like a "normal" test failure with a comparison difference, probably caused by a floating point difference.

Comment: mstest.exe can produce .trx files. You can then open the produced .trx file after test failure and see what exact error you get and where.

Comment: It's a simple "normal" test assert failure such as "Expected 4 apples but found 3". No exceptions in the test result.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792429/some-unit-tests-fail-with-visual-studio-2012-agent-update3-on-windowsxp-sp3

Apparently the wrong framework is infered. Passing /noisolation on the command line when executing your tests is mentioned as a work around. Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts...

1. Floating point math and comparison can actually give different results with/without optimizations. At least they can [in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) They also can, and definitely will, be different on different CPU architectures. Generally speaking, it sounds like a bad idea to have a unit test evaluating pass/fail based on a floating point comparison. Eg, your friend running x64 windows fails the unit tests while you succeed.
2. This extension method issue is a wild goose chase. So what if it mysteriously works if you remove it? Optimized code does crazy shit sometimes, ultimately the problem is your floating point number is DIFFERENT from when its unoptimized. Add an epsilon if a difference is unavoidable, otherwise log its value at every step along the way it is computed and track it down.

Comment: I know that optimizations cause differences in floating point behavior, especially on x86 (less so in x64 where the jitter tends to use SSE). My question wasn't so much "how do I solve this" (I can just avoid the test), but rather I'm curious as to why it appears that the optimizations are made differently when in the mere *presence* of an extension method. I can pinpoint where the difference occurs with/withuot the extension, the question is then: why?